How can I gain large amounts of XP?
What is the best way to get large amounts of XP?
Is is better to create difficult questions?
Is it worth combing the the loads of unanswered questions from years back or is it best to focus on current questions (where there are people you are competing against to get your answer out early)? Is it too difficult to pursue bounties or is it worth it? I would like guidance as a medium (in my opinion) level puzzle solver.
(P.S. I understand the way I have asked this is not good and sounds like a opinion based question - feel free to edit this to phrase the question better.)

In the short term, it's technically creating/answering questions which end up as a HNQ (hot network question), which are questions that are being "promoted" network-wide. The way they end up there is by having a high score count, at least one answer, and not created too long ago. How do you know they end up there? You can't, but they are puzzles that for one reason or another spike the interest of people. Good concept, interesting presentation & title, satisfying solve path, etc. and not so difficult that it'll take a long time to at least get a partial answer. In the end and long-term, [...]

you just have to try stuff out and find the things you are good at in the Puzzling.SE realm, and the reputation (in both senses) will come by itself. Take inspiration from other well-received puzzles and try to solve anything that interests you. Bounties tend to be more difficult, but don't have to be, especially if OP is providing hints regularly. I don't have a Data.SE query ready to analyze answers to new vs old puzzles, they might tend to get a little less upvotes, but it totally depends on the puzzle.

What is your goal of getting reputation? (We don't call it "XP".) Are you pursuing a specific privilege (e.g. close-voting) or do you just want to make the number go up? How much is a "large amount"? You can get a bunch of +2 rep by making good edits. I speak as someone who does a lot of edits... though I no longer get rep, as I passed the 3k threshold where edits are applied automatically.

I guess I should answer this, as the first person (IIRC) to get 100,000 rep on Puzzling SE ...
Creating puzzles is probably the most guaranteed way to earn some rep, if you feel that you're able to create decent ones. There's no time constraint like for solving puzzles, when you need to be the Fastest Gun in the West to find a solution before someone else - you can take your time to put together a really good puzzle and (hopefully!) watch the upvotes and answers flow in after it's posted. Now that question upvotes are worth the same as answer upvotes (since 2019), a good puzzle actually earns you as much rep as a good solution.
For solving puzzles, sit on the homepage. Keep https://puzzling.stackexchange.com open in one of your tabs, so that you'll see a little number pop up in your browser whenever there's new activity, like a new question being posted. Some of those new puzzles you won't be able to solve, of course, or someone else will get there first, but you might get lucky and be the first person to spot an easy one.
Due to the HNQ system, speed is important but not ultra speed. If a good puzzle gets a good answer posted within 8 hours, that's enough to give it a fair shot at reaching the HNQ list. It doesn't matter whether the answer comes within 5 minutes or 5 hours of the question being posted, because questions less than 8 hours old aren't yet eligible for the HNQ algorithm, but if it comes 5 days later, there's no chance of benefiting from HNQ rep windfalls. So, while being fast can be important, don't rush into being super fast if it means sacrificing the quality of your answer.
Finally, you have to be willing to put time into it. In this sense, it's much harder to earn a lot of rep on Puzzling than on other SE sites. Knowledge about a given topic can often be shared relatively quickly, if you have that knowledge or can find it online. But here, both creating puzzles and solving difficult puzzles usually takes a lot of time. It's worth it in the end, for the feeling you get from successfully cracking a tough nut or from getting your creativity recognised, but it's a big time commitment.
